# Can't seem to get the variable. Keep undefined

Tags: node.js, npm

I recently started Node.js development and am still consider a noob.

```
const publicIp = require('public-ip');

publicIp.v4().then(ip => {
    console.log(ip);
});
```

As you can see on the code above I'm actually looking to get public IP.

However, I have totally no idea how do I get the variable of IP out so I can use it. Should you have a similar post, do not hesitate to close and redirect me.

Comment: I have a question also , how are we suppose to know what the author of that package is `resolving` in the `promise` ?

Comment: @0.sh - The [docs](https://github.com/sindresorhus/public-ip#publicipv6options) state: _"Returns a Promise which resolves to your public IPv4 or IPv6 address."_

Comment: guys , what i need is how do i bring this "IP" back out of the quote.

For example if i added a var publicip; before this function. it will go undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node is a single threaded framework. What you have there is an asynchronous function. So in short, you cant "bring" the variable out of the function. You CAN however, call your next function and pass the ip variable to it. For Example:

```
const publicIp = require('public-ip');

publicIp.v4().then(ip => {
    myIPFunction(ip);
});

function myIPFunction(ip){
    //Do something with your IP here
}
```

Your IP value is originally presented in whats called a "Callback". Again, because node is a single threaded framework, it doesnt like to wait on process calls to finish. So rather that hold up the rest of the thread, it allows for these callbacks to take place. But that also means you cant define or reference a variable that doesnt exist yet. So having something like

```
const publicIp = require('public-ip');
var myIP;
publicIp.v4().then(ip => {
    myIP = ip;
});
Console.log(myIP);
```

Wouldnt work because that "ip" variable doesnt exist yet, and therefor hasnt populated the myIP field.

You can read up more about it with these articles

https://nemethgergely.com/async-function-best-practices/

https://medium.com/@thejasonfile/how-node-and-javascript-handle-asynchronous-functions-7feb9fc8a610

Comment: Thank you so much.. as a beginner i couldnt thank you much for giving me a solution.. thanks to this i spend the next 12 hours researchin on callbacks , promises as well as async and await.. now i understand.

Apologies for asking such question again as back in my python .. its a sequential language which gives me mindfuck when asynchronous language comes in ..

Comment: Trust me, I went through the same thing when I first started lol. But once you get the hang of it, it's really simple